# Angular | Generic data table deep level binding using angular material without using angular function

Tags: angular, typescript, html-table, angular-material, angular-binding

I created a generic table component using angular material. I have metadata for column representation as below.

```
`tableColumnBinding: TableColumnMetadata[] = [
 {
  title: 'product.id',
  name: 'id',
  type: 'link',
  path: 'product.status.value', //deep level path
  icon: '',
  isDeepBinding: true
}]`
```

HTML View:

```
`<ng-container *ngFor="let columnMetadata of tableMetadata" [matColumnDef]="columnMetadata.name">
<th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{ columnMetadata.title | transloco}} </th>
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element ">

<div *ngIf="columnMetadata.isDeepBinding; else isNotDeepBinding">
  <span
   (click)="onNavigateButtonClick(element)">
    {{columnDeepDataBinding(element, columnMetadata.path)}}</span>
 </div>
 </td>
</ng-container>`
```

I am looking for an alternative solution to replace `columnDeepDataBinding(element, columnMetadata.path)` with something like `element[columnMetadata.path]` or any other better solution without using angular function to render data.

Comment: maybe `pipe` would look nicer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it by using pipe, Create reusable pipe as like below

```
@Pipe({
   name: 'resolve'
})

export class ResolvePipe implements PipeTransform {
   transform(element: any, path: string): any {
    if (element != null && path != null) {
        return path.split('.').reduce((prev, curr) => {
            return prev ? prev[curr] : null;
        }, element);
    }

    return null;
  }
}
```

import pipe into your module and put it like

```
 <span (click)="onNavigateButtonClick(element)">
    {{element | resolve : columnMetadata.path)}}
 </span>
```

Hope it's works for you

Thanks!.

Comment: @Saddamhussain I just updated my answer, Please check.

Comment: thanks for the answer let me try..